# Does swashbuckle work with .net 35?

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

Does swashbuckle work with .NET 35? If so, where do I get a nuget-package for it?

Thanks!

Comment: You know you can just look at the package on nuget.org and see what frameworks it runs on, right? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/6.0.0-beta902

Answer (score 1):

No it does not work on .NET 3.5.

To verify, try installing `Swashbuckle` in `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Browse`.